# TSQL Calculating daily sum across records with overlapping date ranges

Tags: t-sql, group-by, datediff

I have 3 tables, 1 (PortfolioInstrument) holds instruments (Instrument) held in a portoflio with the holding (Holding) across a date range (DateAdded, DateRemoved).
Another (Price) holds daily (TradeDate) closing prices ([Close]) for each instrument ( Instrument).
A 3rd may be useful, (CalcDate) holds the dates (CalcDate) that we re-calculate the holdings and add and delete instruments from the portfolio.

```
SELECT SUM([Close]*Holding), TradeDate 
FROM Price p1 INNER JOIN PortfolioInstrument pio ON pio.Instrument = p1.Instrument 
AND pio.Portfolio = 3 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TradeDate FROM Price p 
INNER JOIN PortfolioInstrument pi ON pi.Instrument = p.Instrument AND Portfolio = 3
WHERE TradeDate >= pi.DateAdded AND 
(TradeDate < pi.DateRemoved OR pi.DateRemoved IS NULL) 
AND p1.ID = p.ID GROUP BY TradeDate) GROUP BY TradeDate
```

Here is a sample of the PortfolioInstrument data set

```
ID  Portfolio Instrument Holding    DateAdded               DateRemoved

16256   3   410     714.28571       2007-10-01 00:00:00.0   2007-11-01 00:00:00.0
16257   3   611     564.97174       2007-10-01 00:00:00.0   2007-11-01 00:00:00.0
16258   3   538     1,797.75281     2007-10-01 00:00:00.0   2007-11-01 00:00:00.0
...
16302   3   5352    1,067,319.75    2008-02-01 00:00:00.0   2008-04-01 00:00:00.0
16303   3   5353    1,057,800.875   2008-02-01 00:00:00.0   2008-04-01 00:00:00.0
16304   3   11952   0               2008-02-29 00:00:00.0   2008-04-01 00:00:00.0
16305   3   11952   261,484,400     2008-04-01 00:00:00.0   2008-05-01 00:00:00.0
...
16315   3   8374    14,199.99902    2009-01-30 00:00:00.0   <null>
16316   3   11952   246,102,960     2009-01-30 00:00:00.0   2009-02-27 00:00:00.0
16317   3   11952   246,148,912     2009-02-27 00:00:00.0   2009-04-01 00:00:00.0
```

The problem with this is that it includes all Holdings that have a DateRemoved < TradeDate so there is a jump each re-calculation date where they should get removed from the set. Had a look at various DateDiff methods on Stackoverflow but cannot work out how to group using them in this case. Also note that the cash instrument (Instrument = 11952) comes into the portfolio at some point and then gets an entry for every month thereafter, as you can see it reduces to 0 for some months, this should not matter I think in the SQL produced.

Thx.

David

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear why you are using another instance of the same join like that. If you want to exclude particular holdings where `DateRemoved <= TradeDate`, you could just check that directly in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT SUM(p1.[Close]*pio.Holding), TradeDate 
FROM Price p1
INNER JOIN PortfolioInstrument pio
ON pio.Instrument = p1.Instrument AND pio.Portfolio = 3 
WHERE p1.TradeDate >= pio.DateAdded
  AND (p1.TradeDate < pio.DateRemoved OR pio.DateRemoved IS NULL) 
GROUP BY p1.TradeDate
;
```

However, if you want to discard an entire *group* of same `TradeDate` rows in which at least one row satisfies the condition `DateRemoved <= TradeDate`, you could use a HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(p1.[Close]*pio.Holding), TradeDate 
FROM Price p1
INNER JOIN PortfolioInstrument pio
ON pio.Instrument = p1.Instrument AND pio.Portfolio = 3 
GROUP BY p1.TradeDate
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p1.TradeDate <= pio.DateRemoved) THEN 1 END) = 0
;
```

Unlike a WHERE clause, which applies to individual rows, HAVING is evaluated for a group of rows. In this case, the COUNT() function is used to count how many rows in the group have `p1.TradeDate <= pio.DateRemoved`. If there's at least one, the group will be discarded from the output, because the requirement that I'm assuming here is that there be no such rows.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way forward with this, ended up pulling in the raw rows and doing the calculations in the code.

Comment: I can see that I'm late to the show. If there's a chance you might reconsider a SQL solution, please take a look at my suggestions.